# Create a Join in Azure Resource Graph

Tags: sql, azure, powershell, kql

I'm new to KQL and wondering if anyone would know how to do a join with using the query tables below?

```
policyresources
| where type == "microsoft.authorization/policysetdefinitions" |join  advisorresources
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the graph resources

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/samples/samples-by-table?tabs=azure-cli#advisorresources
&

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/samples/samples-by-table?tabs=azure-cli#advisorresources

```
policyresources
| where type == "microsoft.authorization/policysetdefinitions" | extend resourceId = tostring(properties.resourceId) 
| join  (advisorresources | extend resourceId = tostring(properties.resourceMetadata.resourceId)) on resourceId
```

**may** work. Not a 100% sure if the resourceId is the common key. Worth a try though